# sonar web ui is really slow

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

Running SonarQube 4.5.2
Backed by a high performance MS SQL 2012 production cluster

**Rendering the dashboard for a project takes about 15-25 seconds.**

I turned on full debug logging, and in the log I found these

```
17049ms GET /sonar/dashboard/index/69881?did=2
...
19891ms GET /sonar/dashboard/index/69881?did=2
...
19172ms GET /sonar/dashboard/index/69881?did=2
```

And I cannot see any SQL statements in the log that take a unreasonably long time
However, I found a lot of statements similar to this

```
2015.01.14 14:36:50 INFO  http-bio-10.230.49.59-9000-exec-8 web[sql]  219ms Executed SQL: SELECT * FROM [project_measures] WHERE (rule_priority is null and rule_id is null and characteristic_id is null and person_id is null and snapshot_id in (N'8469895',N'8469896',N'8469897',N'8469898',N'8469899',N'8469900',N'8469888',N'8469889',N'8469890',N'8469902',N'8469903',N'8469904',N'8469905',N'8469906',N'8469907',N'8469908',N'8469909',N'8469910',N'8469911',N'8469912',N'8469913',N'8469914',N'8469915',N'8469917',N'8469926',N'8469927',N'8469928',N'8469930',N'8469919',N'8469920',N'8469921',N'8469922',N'8469923',N'8469924',N'8469932',N'8469933',N'8469934',N'8469935',N'8469937',N'8469938',N'8469939',N'8469941',N'8469943',N'8469944',N'8469946',N'8469947',N'8469948',N'8469949',N'8469950',N'8469955',N'8469956',N'8469957',N'8469951',N'8469952',N'8469953',N'8470089',N'8470091',N'8470092',N'8470093',N'8470094',N'8470095',N'8470096',N'8470097',N'8470098',N'8470099',N'8470100',N'8470101',N'8470102',N'8470103',N'8470104',N'8470105',N'8470086',N'8470087',N'8466975',N'8466976',N'8466977',N'8466978',N'8466979',N'8470208',N'8470209',N'8470210',N'8470211',N'8470212',N'8470213',N'8470215',N'8470216',N'8470217',N'8470218',N'8470220',N'8470222',N'8470227',N'8470228',N'8470229',N'8470230',N'8470231',N'8470232',N'8470233',N'8470234',N'8470235',N'8470236',N'8470237',N'8470238',N'8470239',N'8470240',N'8470241',N'8470242',N'8470243',N'8470244',N'8470245',N'8470246',N'8470247',N'8470248',N'8470249',N'8470250',N'8470251',N'8470252',N'8470253',N'8470254',N'8470255',N'8470223',N'8470257',N'8470258',N'8470259',N'8470260',N'8470261',N'8470262',N'8470264',N'8470265',N'8470266',N'8470267',N'8470268',N'8470269',N'8470270',N'8470271',N'8470272',N'8470273',N'8470274',N'8470275',N'8470276',N'8470277',N'8470278',N'8470224',N'8470280',N'8470281',N'8470282',N'8470283',N'8470290',N'8470284',N'8470285',N'8470286',N'8470287',N'8470288',N'8470289',N'8470291',N'8470292',N'8470293',N'8470294',N'8470295',N'8470296',N'8470297',N'8470298',N'8470299',N'8470300',N'8470301',N'8470302',N'8470303',N'8470304',N'8470305',N'8470306',N'8470307',N'8470308',N'8470309',N'8470310',N'8470311',N'8470225',N'8470313',N'8470314',N'8470315',N'8470317',N'8470319',N'8470320',N'8470321',N'8470322',N'8470323',N'8470324',N'8470325',N'8470326',N'8470328',N'8470329',N'8470330',N'8470332',N'8470333',N'8470334',N'8470335',N'8470337',N'8470338',N'8470339',N'8470340',N'8470344',N'8470345',N'8470346',N'8470347',N'8470348',N'8470349',N'8470350',N'8470351',N'8470352',N'8470353',N'8470354',N'8470341',N'8470342',N'8470359',N'8470360',N'8470361',N'8470363',N'8470367',N'8470368',N'8470364',N'8470365',N'8470366',N'8470370',N'8470371',N'8470373',N'8470374',N'8470375',N'8470372',N'8470376',N'8470377',N'8470379',N'8470380',N'8470356',N'8470382',N'8470385',N'8470383',N'8470357',N'8470387',N'8470389',N'8470390',N'8470391',N'8470392',N'8470393',N'8470394',N'8470395',N'8470396',N'8470397',N'8470398',N'8470399',N'8470400',N'8470401',N'8470422',N'8470423',N'8470424',N'8470425',N'8470402',N'8470403',N'8470404',N'8470405',N'8470406',N'8470407',N'8470408',N'8470409',N'8470410',N'8470411',N'8470412',N'8470413',N'8470414',N'8470415',N'8470416',N'8470417',N'8470418',N'8470419',N'8470420',N'8470421',N'8470427',N'8470441',N'8470442',N'8470443',N'8470444',N'8470445',N'8470446',N'8470447',N'8470448',N'8470450',N'8470449',N'8470451',N'8470452',N'8470453',N'8470454',N'8470455',N'8470428',N'8470429',N'8470430',N'8470431',N'8470432',N'8470433',N'8470434',N'8470435',N'8470436',N'8470437',N'8470438',N'8470439',N'8470457',N'8470458',N'8470460',N'8470461',N'8470463',N'8470464',N'8470465',N'8470681',N'8470683',N'8470684',N'8470685',N'8470686',N'8470687',N'8470693',N'8470688',N'8470689',N'8470690',N'8470691',N'8470692',N'8470694',N'8470695',N'8470699',N'8470700',N'8470701',N'8470702',N'8470703',N'8470704',N'8470705',N'8470706',N'8470707',N'8470708',N'8470709',N'8470710',N'8470711',N'8470712',N'8470713',N'8470714',N'8470715',N'8470724',N'8470725',N'8470726',N'8470727',N'8470728',N'8470729',N'8470730',N'8470731',N'8470732',N'8470733',N'8470734',N'8470735',N'8470736',N'8470737',N'8470738',N'8470739',N'8470740',N'8470741',N'8470742',N'8470716',N'8470717',N'8470718',N'8470719',N'8470720',N'8470721',N'8470722',N'8470696',N'8470697',N'8470744',N'8470745',N'8470747',N'8470748',N'8470749',N'8470750',N'8470756',N'8470757',N'8470758',N'8470760',N'8470761',N'8470751',N'8470763',N'8470752',N'8470753',N'8470765',N'8470766',N'8470767',N'8470768',N'8470769',N'8470770',N'8470771',N'8470772',N'8470774',N'8470777',N'8470776',N'8470779',N'8470780',N'8470781',N'8470782',N'8470783',N'8470784',N'8470785',N'8470786',N'8470787',N'8470788',N'8470789',N'8470790',N'8470791',N'8470792',N'8470793',N'8470794',N'8470795',N'8470796',N'8470797',N'8470798',N'8470799',N'8470808',N'8470809',N'8470810',N'8470811',N'8470812',N'8470813',N'8470814',N'8470815',N'8470816',N'8470817',N'8470818',N'8470819',N'8470820',N'8470821',N'8470822',N'8470823',N'8470824',N'8470825',N'8470826',N'8470827',N'8470800',N'8470801',N'8470802',N'8470803',N'8470804',N'8470805',N'8470806',N'8470829',N'8470830',N'8470831',N'8470832',N'8470833',N'8470834',N'8470754',N'8470836',N'8470837',N'8470839',N'8470840',N'8470845',N'8470846',N'8470843',N'8470841',N'8468773',N'8468785',N'8468786',N'8468787',N'8468788',N'8468789',N'8468790',N'8468791',N'8468774',N'8468775',N'8468776',N'8468777',N'8468778',N'8468779',N'8468780',N'8468781',N'8468782',N'8468783',N'8468793',N'8468794',N'8468795',N'8468797',N'8468798',N'8468799',N'8468800',N'8468801',N'8468802',N'8468803',N'8468804',N'8468805',N'8471049',N'8471050',N'8471051',N'8471052',N'8471053',N'8471054',N'8471055',N'8471056',N'8471057',N'8471059',N'8471060',N'8471061',N'8471062',N'8471063',N'8471064',N'8471065',N'8471066',N'8471067',N'8471068',N'8471069',N'8471070',N'8471071',N'8471072',N'8471073',N'8471074',N'8471075',N'8471076',N'8471077',N'8471078',N'8471079',N'8471080',N'8471081',N'8471082',N'8471083',N'8471084',N'8471085',N'8471086',N'8471087',N'8471088',N'8471089',N'8471090',N'8471091',N'8471092',N'8471094',N'8471095',N'8468848',N'8468849',N'8468859',N'8468860',N'8468861',N'8468862',N'8468863',N'8468864',N'8468865',N'8468866',N'8468867',N'8468868',N'8468869',N'8468870',N'8468851',N'8468852',N'8468853',N'8468854',N'8468855',N'8468856',N'8468857',N'8468872',N'8468878',N'8468879',N'8468880',N'8468881',N'8468882',N'8468883',N'8468884',N'8468885',N'8468886',N'8468887',N'8468888',N'8468898',N'8468899',N'8468900',N'8468901',N'8468902',N'8468903',N'8468904',N'8468905',N'8468906',N'8468907',N'8468908',N'8468909',N'8468910',N'8468911',N'8468912',N'8468913',N'8468914',N'8468915',N'8468916',N'8468889',N'8468890',N'8468891',N'8468892',N'8468893',N'8468894',N'8468895',N'8468896',N'8468918',N'8468919',N'8468920',N'8468921',N'8468922',N'8468925',N'8468926',N'8468927',N'8468928',N'8468929',N'8468930',N'8468923',N'8468934',N'8468932',N'8468936',N'8468937',N'8468873',N'8468874',N'8468939',N'8468940',N'8468941',N'8468942',N'8468943',N'8468944',N'8468945',N'8468947',N'8468948',N'8468956',N'8468957',N'8468958',N'8468959',N'8468960',N'8468961',N'8468962',N'8468963',N'8468949',N'8468950',N'8468951',N'8468952',N'8468953',N'8468954',N'8468875',N'8468876',N'8468965',N'8468845',N'8468967',N'8468968',N'8468969',N'8468970',N'8468971',N'8468972',N'8468974',N'8468846',N'8468976',N'8468977',N'8468978',N'8468979',N'8468980',N'8468984',N'8468981',N'8468982',N'8468983',N'8468985',N'8468987',N'8469162',N'8469165',N'8469166',N'8469167',N'8469168',N'8469169',N'8469171',N'8469172',N'8469175',N'8469174',N'8469176',N'8469177',N'8469178',N'8469179',N'8469181',N'8469182',N'8469183',N'8469185',N'8469186',N'8469188',N'8469190',N'8469163',N'8469192',N'8469193',N'8469194',N'8469195',N'8469196',N'8469197',N'8469198',N'8469203',N'8469204',N'8469205',N'8469206',N'8469207',N'8469208',N'8469209',N'8469210',N'8469211',N'8469212',N'8469199',N'8469200',N'8469201',N'8469214',N'8469215',N'8469216',N'8469217',N'8469219',N'8469221',N'8469222',N'8469224',N'8469226',N'8469236',N'8469237',N'8469239',N'8469230',N'8469241',N'8469231',N'8469232',N'8469243',N'8469244',N'8469246',N'8469247',N'8469248',N'8469249',N'8469250',N'8469251',N'8469252',N'8469233',N'8469234',N'8469227',N'8469254',N'8469228',N'8469256',N'8469258',N'8469260',N'8469262',N'8469264',N'8469265',N'8469279',N'8469280',N'8469281',N'8469282',N'8469283',N'8469284',N'8469266',N'8469267',N'8469268',N'8469269',N'8469270',N'8469271',N'8469272',N'8469273',N'8469274',N'8469275',N'8469276',N'8469277',N'8469286',N'8469287',N'8469288',N'8469289',N'8469291',N'8469293',N'8469294',N'8469295',N'8469296',N'8469297',N'8469298',N'8469299',N'8469300',N'8469301',N'8469302',N'8469303',N'8469304',N'8469305',N'8469306',N'8469307',N'8469308',N'8469309',N'8469310',N'8469337',N'8469338',N'8469339',N'8469340',N'8469341',N'8469342',N'8469343',N'8469344',N'8469345',N'8469346',N'8469347',N'8469348',N'8469349',N'8469350',N'8469351',N'8469353',N'8469352',N'8469354',N'8469355',N'8469356',N'8469357',N'8469358',N'8469359',N'8469360',N'8469361',N'8469362',N'8469363',N'8469364',N'8469365',N'8469366',N'8469367',N'8469368',N'8469369',N'8469370',N'8469371',N'8469372',N'8469373',N'8469374',N'8469375',N'8469376',N'8469377',N'8469311',N'8469312',N'8469313',N'8469314',N'8469315',N'8469316',N'8469317',N'8469318',N'8469319',N'8469320',N'8469321',N'8469322',N'8469323',N'8469324',N'8469325',N'8469326',N'8469327',N'8469328',N'8469329',N'8469330',N'8469331',N'8469332',N'8469333',N'8469334',N'8469335',N'8469379',N'8469380',N'8469382',N'8469383',N'8469384',N'8469385',N'8469386',N'8469387',N'8469388',N'8469389',N'8469390',N'8469391',N'8469392',N'8469393',N'8469394',N'8469395',N'8469396',N'8469397',N'8469398',N'8469399',N'8469400',N'8469401',N'8469402',N'8469403',N'8469404',N'8469406',N'8469407',N'8469408',N'8469409',N'8469410',N'8469411',N'8469412',N'8469413',N'8469414',N'8469415',N'8469416',N'8469417',N'8469418',N'8469419',N'8469420',N'8469422',N'8469421',N'8469423',N'8469424',N'8469425',N'8469426',N'8469427',N'8469429',N'8469430',N'8469431',N'8469432',N'8469433',N'8469434',N'8469435',N'8469436',N'8469437',N'8469438',N'8469439',N'8469440',N'8469442',N'8469444',N'8469456',N'8469457',N'8469458',N'8469459',N'8469460',N'8469461',N'8469462',N'8469463',N'8469464',N'8469446',N'8469447',N'8469448',N'8469449',N'8469450',N'8469451',N'8469452',N'8469453',N'8469454',N'8469481',N'8469466',N'8469467',N'8469468',N'8469469',N'8469470',N'8469471',N'8469472',N'8469473',N'8469474',N'8469475',N'8469476',N'8469477',N'8469478',N'8469479',N'8469480',N'8469483',N'8469484',N'8469485',N'8469486',N'8471004',N'8471005',N'8471006',N'8471007',N'8471008',N'8471019',N'8471020',N'8471021',N'8471022',N'8471023',N'8471009',N'8471010',N'8471011',N'8471012',N'8471013',N'8471025',N'8471026',N'8471014',N'8471016',N'8471015',N'8471017',N'8466575',N'8466576',N'8466577',N'8466578',N'8466579',N'8466580',N'8466581',N'8466582',N'8466584',N'8466585',N'8466587',N'8466589') and metric_id in (N'3',N'53',N'185'))
```

This lead me to execute

```
select count(*) from sonar.snapshots
```

= 16003

Which I find to be a very high number?

What is also interesting is that rendering the dashboard for a new project (about a month of analysis) takes half the time of a project that has been analysed for a couple of 
years now.

We have about 20-30 projects, but only a few of them are really active. 
I would say only about 3-4 active projects. 
The rest are only analysed approx 5-10 times a year, so these projects should not really accumulate snapshots.

The developers on the team are getting frustrated by the page loading time, so any help on tuning this is much appreciated!

Is there a way of cleaning the Sonar DB for all history?

**Update**

The dashboard contains

- scale rating
- technical debt
- dir tangle inded
- unit tests
- integrations tests
- complexity
- documentation
- lines of code
- duplications
- false positives
- quality gate
- most violated rules
- most violated components
- hotspots by issues
- technical debt pyramid
- events
- issues
- my unresolved issues
- unresolved issues pr assignee
- issues og metrics
- history table x 2
- clirr
- project motion chart
- project file bubble chart

I have created a more "focused" dashboard, containing fewer widgets. 
This has reduced the dashboard loading time by 50%, down to 10-11 seconds. 
Better, but also rather slow. 
The widgets for this dashboard are

- quality gate
- sqale ratine
- technical debt
- unit tests
- integration tests
- dir tangle index
- complexity
- history table
- false positives
- issues
- unresolved issues per assignee
- my unresolved issues
- most violated rules
- most violated components
- technical debt

For the newer, smaller project, loading time is reduced from about 12 to 9 seconds, so I'm not seeing a doubleing of performance here.

Log can be found http://pastebin.com/zJcEH4Ex

Comment: Can you please give more details? Most notably: which widgets are configured on this dashboard? Typically, if you have the Project Bubble Chart widget, this can really slow down the page if you have lots of files in your project.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarQubeTeam - I have updated the post with relevant info

Comment: The "focused" dashboard that you've set up should load very fast because apart from the History widget, no widget checks snapshots of the past. Can you check again what's going on in the "FULL" logs when you display this dashboard?

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarQubeTeam Where can I post the log? There is not enough space for the log. The complete request now took 5774 ms. However, when adding up the milliseconds for each log statement it only adds up to 890.

Comment: You can paste the log on pastebin.com and update your question with the link to your paste.

Comment: Log added to pastebin @Fabrice-SonarQubeTeam

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarQubeTeam Have you found time to look at the log?

Comment: I've just took a look at the logs, and nothing's special there. Which version of Java are you using to run the server? Have you activated the "-server" mode?

Comment: I'm using 1.8.0_25.  See dump of systeminfo here http://pastebin.com/wTXrtVQS  And I have activated the -server argument in wrapper.conf

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarQubeTeam Sorry, -server activated not in wrapper.conf, but in sonar.properties. Contents here http://pastebin.com/AU9tXBU5

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarQubeTeam Have you found the time to look at the systeminfo/props? The performance is really killing us at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When upgrading to version 5.0.1 the performance issues were resolved.